# Como evitar LazyExceptions?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

A minha aplicação enfrenta inúmeros problemas de LazyExceptions e o que causa uma "sujeira" no log do servidor. Entendo que ocorrem porque a conexão com o banco de dados já foi fechada e estou tentando recuperar algum atributo/objeto que não foi inicializado.

O problema mais recente que tive foi obter uma LazyException no filter porque os lojistas de ProdutoValor não estavam inicializados. Estas ocorrem somente **num fluxo específico do sistema.**

Service

```
List<ProdutoValorETO> valores = mgrProdutoValorEDAO.findByProdutoId(produto.getId());
Optional<ProdutoValorETO> optionalProdValor = valores.stream()
                        .filter(v -> v.getLojista().getId().equals(lojista.getId()))
                        .findFirst();
```

DAO

```
public List<ProdutoValorETO> findByProdutoId(Long id) {
        if (id != null) {
            String query =
                    " SELECT * " +
                            " FROM produtovalor " +
                            " WHERE idproduto = " + id + " AND ativo = TRUE; ";
            SQLQuery eQuery = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query).addEntity(ProdutoValorETO.class);
            List<ProdutoValorETO> lista = CastUtils.castList(eQuery.list(), ProdutoValorETO.class);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Eu resolvi da seguinte forma mas me parece mais um workaround:

```
public List<ProdutoValorETO> findByProdutoId(Long id) {
        if (id != null) {
            String query =
                    " SELECT * " +
                            " FROM produtovalor " +
                            " WHERE idproduto = " + id + " AND ativo = TRUE; ";
            SQLQuery eQuery = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query).addEntity(ProdutoValorETO.class);
            List<ProdutoValorETO> lista = CastUtils.castList(eQuery.list(), ProdutoValorETO.class);
            for (ProdutoValorETO item : lista) {
                Hibernate.initialize(item);
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Configuração

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" />
    <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="30000"/>
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="30000" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="600000"/>
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="registerMbeans" value="true"/>
    <!-- <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/> -->
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="select 1"/>

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.example.*.to"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

ProdutoValorETO

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idProduto")
    private ProdutoETO produto;
```

ProdutoETO

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "produto", targetEntity = ProdutoValorETO.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    private List<ProdutoValorETO> valores;
```

1. Quando realizamos um fluxo muito grande no sistema, é mais provável que ocorrerá uma Lazy? Eu obti a lista de valores uma linha acima de quando tento acessar os items e já obtive a exception.
2. Há algum mecanismo no Spring JPA ou nas novas versões do Hibernate para tratar melhor isto? (Essa aplicação usa Spring 3 Hibernate 3.2)
3. Há alguma implicação em ocorrer Lazy ao escrever direto o select ao invés de usar Hibernate criteria?
4. Há melhores maneiras de resolver esse caso (sem ser Eager)?

Comment: Tem um mini padrão de projetos (que quebra outro padrão) chamado [Open Session in View](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView). Talvez possa te ajudar.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque suas entidades envolvidas no relacionamento, por favor. Além disso, por que seu método `findByProdutoId` está retornando uma `List`? Ele não deveria retornar apenas um objeto?

Comment: @FelipeMarinho Adicionado. Um produto possui uma lista de valores, de acordo com a unidade que você comprar é retornado um valor, regras de negócio.

Comment: @DanielaMorais Dê uma olhada nas respostas que já deram. O `Join Fetch` é provavelmente a melhor solução para o seu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quando realizamos um fluxo muito grande no sistema, é mais provável
>   que ocorrerá uma Lazy? Eu obti a lista de valores uma linha acima de
>   quando tento acessar os items e já obtive a exception.

Sim, se você estiver usando as entidades fora da transação.

Creio que você possa organizar seu código de uma maneira que as entidades não sejam usadas **fora** de uma transação, evitando o erro. Você pode conseguir isto mapeando as informações para outras classes (DTOs) que, elas assim, ficam fora da transação, sendo usadas para preencher telas, relatórios, etc.

Toda aplicação que vi com muitos problemas de `LazyException` eram porque as entidades eram usadas fora da transação. Inclusive, esta é uma prática a ser evitada por diferentes motivos que vão além do `LazyException`.

> Há algum mecanismo no Spring JPA ou nas novas versões do Hibernate
>   para tratar melhor isto? (Essa aplicação usa Spring 3 Hibernate 3.2)

Existem recursos para auxiliar que você tenha já uma informação sem depender da transação aberta: `EAGER` (usado no relacionamento, mas [não recomendo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17847289/2387977)) e o `FETCH` (usado na consulta).

> Há alguma implicação em ocorrer Lazy ao escrever direto o select ao
>   invés de usar Hibernate criteria?

Não que eu conheça. Consultas equivalentes em JPQL e Criteria deveriam gerar o mesmo SQL.

> Há melhores maneiras de resolver esse caso (sem ser Eager)?

Sim, utilizando [FETCH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17431312/2387977):

```
SELECT pv
FROM produtovalor pv
JOIN FETCH pv.lojista 
WHERE pv.idproduto = :id AND pv.ativo = TRUE;
```

Comment: Para quem votou negativo: gostaria de saber qual o motivo da minha resposta não ser útil.

Comment: Não entendi o negativo tb! Uma dúvida: Num contexto de domain driven design, vejo as entities sendo usadas no contexto das services e não somente dos DAOs/Repositories. O que vc quer dizer "muitos problemas de LazyException eram porque as entidades eram usadas fora da transação."?

Comment: Precisaria entender no projeto como está o controle de transação entre as classes (se você tiver usando este controle). Vou dar um exemplo. No Spring se um Service chamar um Repository para buscar uma entidade, a entidade associada a esta entidade buscada poderá dar erro de LazyException (exemplo: entidade.getOutraEntidade()). Isto só é resolvido com o `@Transactional` no Service, assim ele abrirá uma transação com o banco de dados a partir deste momento e todo "get" de entidade a partir do Service fará a busca no banco de dados sem o LazyException.

Answer (score 0):

> Como evitar LazyExceptions?

Infelizmente não existe uma resposta pronta para essa pergunta, a solução depende sempre do contexto.

> 1. Quando realizamos um fluxo muito grande no sistema, é mais provável que ocorrerá uma Lazy?Eu obti a lista de valores uma linha acima de quando tento acessar os items e já obtive a exception.

A LazyException é sempre lançada quando você tenta acessar uma coleção que não está "carregada" e a sessão foi fechada. O que pode estar acontecendo, é que quando você faz uma busca, o construtor padrão da entidade é acionado(você pode colocar um breakpoint no construtor para verificar tal fato), talvez no construtor você já está tentando acessar a coleção, ou em algum outro lugar, que você ainda não conseguiu visualizar.

> 2. Há algum mecanismo no Spring JPA ou nas novas versões do Hibernate para tratar melhor isto? (Essa aplicação usa Spring 3 Hibernate 3.2)

Considerando que o Spring 4 já está há bastante tempo consolidado no mercado, e que o Spring 5 acabou de ser lançado, e ainda que o Hibernate está atualmente na versão 5.x, eu diria que uma atualização seria muito bem vindo do ponto de vista tecnológico, mas em sistemas legados isso nem sempre é possível. Mas a questão da LazyException, não está diretamente relacionada com as versões dos frameworks, podemos dizer que a LazyExection seria um mecanismo de defesa para evitar uma sobrecarga, **o framework quer que você só carregue as coleções quando for realmente necessário**, e este é o segredo para resolver o problema.

> 3. Há alguma implicação em ocorrer Lazy ao escrever direto o select ao invés de usar Hibernate criteria?

O Hibernate é uma implementação do JPA, então quando você "escreve a SQL direto no códgio", utilizando uma query nativa, tal query ainda é gerenciada pela camada de persistência da aplicação, perceba no seu código que você solicitou a sessão atual e depois solicitou a criação da query nativa:  `SQLQuery eQuery = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query).addEntity(ProdutoValorETO.class);`, assim sendo, não há diferença de uma LazyException lançada por uma Criteria ou por uma query nativa.

> 4. Há melhores maneiras de resolver esse caso (sem ser Eager)?

Bom, o eager realmente é uma alternativa muito perigosa, pois sempre irá trazer as coleções já carregadas, o que pode afetar o desempenho de forma muito significativa. Uma outra opção, é a já dita pelo Igor Venturelli nos comentários, usar Open Session in View, você pode ver uma breve referência para o assunto [aqui](http://blog.caelum.com.br/enfrentando-a-lazyinitializationexception-no-hibernate/).

Eu particularmente sugiro entender o contexto da aplicação e saber quando devo trazer as coleções e quando não devo. Por exemplo, vamos supor um sisteminha de controle de vendas, onde a entidade venda tem uma coleção de itens de venda. Neste sistema existe a tela de consulta de vendas, onde vai ser exibida a lista de vendas, mas somente a data, o cliente, e a situação da venda. Então, eu não preciso trazer os itens da venda na minha consulta que faz a busca da listagem de vendas. Mas quando o usuário clicar no botão de ver/editar venda, será preciso exibir os itens de cada venda, ai neste momento eu busco os itens, usando por exemplo o join fetch :

```
FROM Venda v JOIN FETCH v.itens
```

Uma boa referência para join fetch pode ser vista [aqui](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/4700__JPA_Query_Join_Fetch.htm).

Para o caso de quando você obter uma LazyException antes mesmo de acessar a coleção, você pode atribuir uma coleção vazia (ou até mesmo nula) antes de exceção ser lançada, mas como é possível imaginar, isto é seria uma gambiarra.